# Why doesn't this operational value work?

Tags: java

I'm writing an assignment for one of my classes, and i'm trying to use mutiple boolean conditions for the first time. the specific problem is that

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) && (activity.equals("0"));
{
    System.out.println("Male");
}
```

is returning an error, specifically "Java; illegal start of expression"

Is there a reason for this? Both variables exist, so that is not the issue (I'm pretty sure)

Comment: Take a careful look at your paretheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line :

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) && (activity.equals("0"));
```

to

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && (activity.equals("0"))
```

if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M")**)** && (activity.equals("0"))**;**

Extra **parenthesis** and **semicolon** is what you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

`if( gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M") )` is an if statement all by itself.

Adding `&& (activity.equals("0"));` confuses Java for two reasons.

1. The `&&` needs to be within the first `(` and the last `)` like this

`if ( conditionOne && conditionTwo )` you have this

`if (conditionOne) && (conditionTwo)`

2. The other problem is you have a semicolon at the end of your if statement. When you do this it cuts the if statement off early and it will execute the lines of code in the brackets regardless of the result of the if statement.

Comment: Ok, you're right. However, they will be executed regardless of the result of the if condition. Thanks, I'll change my answer to reflect this.